# Executing shell command using child_process in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, child-process

Trying to execute shell command(any) from the browser and printing the result on the Ui using child_process.

unable to fetch the results from command line asynchronously.Am I missing something here ?

```
   const exec = require('child_process').exec;
    app.post('/plan',(req, res) => {

      let cmd = exec('dir');
      let output = "";
      cmd.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        //console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
        output += data;
       });
      res.send(output);                          //not working
      console.log(output);                       //its empty
      cmd.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
          console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
       });
      cmd.on('close', (code) => {
         console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
      });

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell command runs asynchronously. You need to send the response from within the callback function so that it sends the result when it is finished executing.

```
  cmd.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    output += data;
    res.send(output); 
   });
```

Might be cleaner to do it like this:

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
app.post('/plan',(req, res) => {
  exec('dir', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
      res.status(500).send(stderr);
      return;
    }
    res.send(stdout);
  });
});
```

Comment: how do i access the stdout on ui ? the result which im recieving is 
`body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "basic"
url: "http://localhost:3000/plan"
__proto__: Response`

Comment: You need to read the response stream as text https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response. Try `fetch('http://localhost:3000/plan').then(response => response.text()).then(console.log)`